# What's URD in iptables?

Tags: iptables, network-protocols

I've been playing around with various `iptables` configurations lately, and I noticed that adding a rule which involves `--dport 465` (usually reserved for `smtps`) results in the human-readable `dpt:urd` showing up when listing rules with `iptables -L`.

I've never heard of this protocol, and an (admittedly superficial) web search doesn't reveal much about it.

What's URD, and why does `iptables` show this instead of the (arguably more well-known, or at least better-documented) `smtps`?

Answer (score 6):

```
[me@risby ~]$ grep urd /etc/services
urd             465/tcp         smtps   # URL Rendesvous Directory for SSM / SMTP over SSL (TLS)
```

[This CISCO documentation](http://ftp.ipsyn.net/pub/mirrors/cisco/ftpeng.cisco.com/ipmulticast/ssm/) suggests that

> URD is the designated transition solution for content providers that
>   want to use not (yet) SSM enabled receiver applications. URD allows to
>   enable existing applications to be SSM capable without modifying any
>   receiver host software (application nor operating system) - as long as
>   the application is started via a web browser. URD stands for "URL
>   Rendezvous Directory" and relies on the last-hop router towards a SSM
>   receiver host to intercept URLs from a webserver to detect the source
>   address of the SSM channel.

and moreover that

> Source Specific Multicast (SSM) is an extension of IP Multicast in
>   which datagram traffic is forwarded to receivers from only those
>   multicast sources for which the receivers have explicitly expressed
>   interest.

This is (one reason) why you should **always, always** use `iptables -L -n -v` for listing rules!